# Sharepoint - How to sum of a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to sum my "Estimation" calculated column, how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the number column, which has a built-in sum function. Other types of columns do not have this function.

1.For the classic list, you could use code to make the "Calculated" column to show the totals.

Reference:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151697/display-sum-of-a-calculated-column

2.For the modern list, you could use flow.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89029/total-of-a-calculated-column-on-sharepoint-365-and.html